# Problem with updating user profile because of PUT method is not supported [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update my user profile and I have encounter problem with

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

I have defined the route and I'm not sure why this happen.

`web.php`

```
Route::get('/user/{id}',[UserController::class,'show'])->name('user.profile');
Route::get('/edit/user/',[UserController::class,'edit'])->name('user.edit');
Route::post('/edit/user/',[UserController::class,'update'])->name('user.update');
```

`UserController`

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        if ($user){
            $validate = null;
            if (Auth::user()->email === $request ['email']) {
                $validate = $request->validate([
                    'name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required',
                    'phone' => 'required',
                    'address' => 'required'
                ]);
            } else {
                $validate = $request->validate([
                    'name' => 'required',
                    'email' => 'required',
                    'phone' => 'required',
                    'address' => 'required'
                ]);
            }
            if($validate){
 
                $user->name = $request['name'];
                $user->email =$request['email'];
                $user->phone = $request['phone'];
                $user->address = $request['address'];

                $user->save();
                $request ->session->flash('success', 'Profile have been updated');
                return redirect()->back();
            } else{
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

`edit.blade.php`

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('user.update',$user->id)}}" method="POST">
              @csrf
              @method('PUT')

              @if(session('success'))
              <div class="alert alert-success"  role="alert">
                 {{session('success')}}
              </div>
              @endif

                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  value="{{$user->name}}">
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: you didn't define it as `PUT` you defined it as `POST` so the method doesn't match .. your form is spoofing the method as `PUT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **@method('PUT')** from blade file -

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('user.update',$user->id)}}" method="POST">
          @csrf

          @if(session('success'))
          <div class="alert alert-success"  role="alert">
             {{session('success')}}
          </div>
          @endif

            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  value="{{$user->name}}">
                </div>
              </div>
```